# Como se puede aplicar un Tooltip independiente para todas las filas de una sola Columna en JSF

Tags: mysql, jsf

```
<h4>        
                                                    <p:outputLabel id="ip_fuentes"
                                                        value="#{varPE.index+1}.#{pregunt.textoPreguntaEstrategia}"
                                                        
                                                        styleClass="col-sm-3 control-label" 
                                                        required="true"/>
                                                    
                                                        <p:tooltip for="ip_fuentes" showEffect="clip"
                                                            hideEffect="explode" style="width:300px;"
                                                            position="right">
                                                            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                                                                <h5 class="text-center text-muted">
                                                                    <strong>#{idm.analisis_nuevo_lbFuentes}</strong>
                                                                </h5>
                                                                <p class="well text-justify text-muted"
                                                                    style="font-family: arial;">#{idm.help_ingreso}</p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </p:tooltip>
                                                        <p:message for="ip_fuentes" display="text" />               
                                                     </h4
```

Lo que sucede es que llamo a una columna de la tabla de la base de datos, estas son preguntas asignadas en cada fila que se muestran en un formulario. Lo que sucede es que solo a la primera pregunta que aparece  información con el tooltip, pero quiero agregar su propia información en un tooltip a cada una de las preguntas "Filas", alguna solución. Gracias.

Comment: Tu pregunta me confunde. A JSF le da igual de donde vengan los datos, cuando hablamos de columnas es porque se presentan los datos en un *datatable* pero tu código no parece incluir nada de datatable. Por favor pon un código más representativo de como defines el datatable y la variable asociada, a cambio puedes simplicficar las partes no necesarias (por ejemplo con un tooltip más sencillo).

Comment: #{pregunt.textoPreguntaEstrategia} Pregunt hace referencia a la tabla.

Comment: "pregunt". da una lista de titulo de cada pregunta pero solo asigna un tooltip al primero de la lista, lo que deseo es para cada pregunta  asignar un tooltip